# Batch add a formula in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-formula, batch-processing

I have a spreadsheet with hundreds of cells containing formulas like `=('Pricing Master'!$E135*'Pricing Master'!$L$29)`. I would like to batch add the ROUNDUP formula, so that they all read, for example, `=ROUNDUP('Pricing Master'!$E135*'Pricing Master'!$L$29,0)`. A simple Replace All will not work, as it requires both the function call preceding as well as the Number argument following. Not providing both at the same time produces an error. This creates an issue with batch editing using Replace All.

I am sure that there is a way to do this with the Paste Special function, although if there is another way I would be glad to hear it.

Comment: You can do some interesting things with wildcards in `Find` and `Replace` so you want to explore that. If not, I think VBA will be the way to do it.

Comment: For a VBA approach, check this page: https://excel.tips.net/T003303_Wildcards_in_Replace_With_Text.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach is this and I do this often with large sheets with many formulae:

One : select the row(s) or column(s) you want to work with,

Then edit/replace “=(“ with “xyxy(” (I use xyxy as it just doesn’t come up...

Now all replace operations will be quicker as there is no re-calc happening...

So now do edit/replace “xyxy” with “xyxyroundup(“ and “)” with “,0)”

Then just replace “xyxy” with “=“

And wait for it to finish its calculations...

Comment: I don't know any VBA yet to really apply the other recommendations--this little _xyxy_ game you played really made you the hero today, thanks.

Comment: Just make sure you write down the original and target to make sure that you get what you want and ALWAYS work on a copy - trying to undo a messed up replace is a pain in the .... Glad it helps though.

Answer (score 0):

loop through each cell and add formula to the original formula. Like this

```
Sub updateFor()
Dim r As Range

For Each r In Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)''only cells with formula in

            r.Formula = "=ROUNDUP(" & Mid(r.Formula, 2) & ",0)"
Next r
End Sub
```

just replace the selection with the range you want to edit

if you arnt familiar with vba heres a quick guide

1. press ALT + F11 to show the vba editor
2. from insert menu select module
3. module1 should appear in the project window in the top left,
       click on this
4. a large window should open on the right paste the above code in
5. go back to your worksheet and select the cells you want to roundup
6. goto to the view ribbon click the macro button on the far right
7. select the macro 'updateFor' and press run